# claim or take something?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> If no one claims the items before going off work, please dispose them.

In the above context should I use claim or take…away. Is "going off work" or "quitting time " more proper in the sentence?

Comment: Proofreading is off topic. Still: *If no one claims the items by the end of the day, dispose them.* Use 'claim' because claiming is showing that the things belong to them; taking does not mean that. Going off work/quitting time is not good here. Instead, use 'end of the day.' The scene is of 'office' I guess.

Answer (score 1):

> If no one claims the items before going off work, please dispose them.

It should be:

> If no one claims the items before **you finish work**, please dispose **of** them.

It could also be: "before the end of the day", "before the end of the working day", "before close of business".

"Takes" would imply that anyone is allowed to take them regardless of whether they own them.  "Claims" means that the person is expected to say that the items belong to him or her.

If you've said to your staff that if anyone has lost their X, Y and Z, they should collect them from the office before closing time or they'll be thrown away, you should tell your colleague "If no one claims the items...".

If you've said to your staff that the items are being given away, you should say "If no one takes the items...".

You could say "takes" regardless, but it would suggest that people will be able to walk straight in and take the items, possibly even when the office is unattended.

"Claims" doesn't necessarily mean that the employee will be expected to provide any evidence of ownership (usually this is not the case).